# Efficient dispatch from "name",number to template handler functions

Tags: c++, templates, dispatch

I have an input file that looks like:

```
op1000,3,free-form,data
op1002,1,other,data,1.0
```

I have a number of template functions:

```
template<int version>
static bool op1000(const char * s) { /* parse free-form data */ }
```

My current method is:

```
struct op2func
{
  const char * op;
  const int version;
  bool (*parse)(const char *s);
};

op2func mapping[] =
{
{ "op1000",0,op1000<0> },
{ "op1000",1,op1000<1> },
{ "op1000",2,op1000<2> },
{ "op1000",3,op1000<3> },
{ "op1002",0,op1000<0> },
{ "op1002",1,op1000<1> }
};
```

This involves a linear search for a matching name and version -- this used to be a binary search, but adding new entries in the right place was too challenging for some developers; along with the overhead of a `strcmp()` per entry.

There HAS to be a better way to handle this scenario.   A C++11 solution is preferred if practical.

Ideally, I'd like something that takes a list of possible operation names and generates a compile-time switch.

Comment: There is a simple and pragmatic solution: Insert a pre-build step which patches (corrects) your source code and use binary search afterwards. (You could also consider to "out-source" the table into a separate file and generate an include in the pre-build step if you feel inconvenient with "patching".)

Comment: My other simple and pragmatic solution is to insert a run-time check (`assert()`) into the code which ensures that the table is correct or `abort()`s otherwise (with an indication what's wrong). With `assert()`, it's only active when `NDEBUG` is not defined (i.e. in the Debug target in VisualStudio). So, it doesn't affect the deployed binaries.